# click event on a input text box does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my input :

```
<input name="DeviceIP" class="k-input k-textbox" type="text" data-bind="value:DeviceIP">
```

here is my js which is not working

```
$('input[name="DeviceIP"]').click(function () {  alert("test") });
```

Comment: Have you include jquery library file?

Comment: Not working? Any error. Please be more specific

Comment: Code seems fine, have you included the jQuery library? If so, what version and what are the errors in the console saying?

Comment: @RakeshSoni what do you mean?

Comment: Is the input field dynamically rendered?

Comment: @Volem not working,nothing happens as I expecting to get "test" alert

Comment: Add more information so people can help you.

Comment: click on input text? why not on change or blur or keyup or input or any other event?

Comment: Include <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> before your js

Comment: Are you getting any browser console error ? if yes can you share it please?

Comment: just include jquery!! it works just fine https://jsfiddle.net/fsd_taha/7qvzzkc9/

Answer (score 0):

This code works as expected. Here is a minimal example of working code (same as yours, only jQuery is included)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="DeviceIP" class="k-input k-textbox" type="text" data-bind="value:DeviceIP">
</body>
</html>
<script>
  $('input[name="DeviceIP"]').click(function() {
    alert("test")
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("input[name='DeviceIP']").click(function () {  alert("test")});
```

Answer (score -1):

The code should work fine,

The common reason for this kind of errors are the misconsception of binding events via JS/JQuery.

When you use $('some selector').click(fn) syntax this means :

```
JQuery will bind "fn" click event to the Elements 
that have already been attached to the DOM (to HTML)
```

It will not attach events to the newly/dynamically created/attached elements. You still have to bind related events to those after they are attached to dom or to their JS reference.